# How to sort class objects in PHP v 5.2.17?

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I was working on my local server where I have php 5.3+ and usort with anonymous works great.

But on the hosting provider they have php 5.2.17 where usort doesn't work in the way I used it.

Here is the code On Local [PHP 5.3+]

```
class Flight {
    ...
    var $dateLeg;
    ...
}
usort($flights, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->dateLeg) - strtotime($b->dateLeg);
});
```

usort here is called in a different function in different file. And $flights contains objects of Flight Class.

How to sort it in PHP 5.2.17.

Please help.

Comment: `usort($flights, "function_name");`

Comment: If there's no way to get any version of PHP 5.3+ at your host, find a new host. 5.2 is ancient and dead.

Comment: thanks for all negative voting.. i certainly don't understand stackoverflow users sometimes. Anyway.. thanks for help.

Comment: Downvote == *"Question does not show any research effort"*. Simply reading the fine manual for [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) would have shown you the correct way to do it.

Comment: Hi Deceze.. I did research. However I was confused about how to use that. don't you think that if I asked this detailed question.. i would have done research.. I just wanted to understand how usort or something else would work.. anyways.. your vote teaches me a lesson.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a non-anonymous function:

```
function sortFlights($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->dateLeg) - strtotime($b->dateLeg);
}

usort($flights, 'sortFlights');
```